# What are the reasons for having special names for God/ Jesus?

Tags: names-of-god

I was watching the "Truth Project" (a religious DVD) and the speaker kept referring to "Jehovah Jireh".    A recent [answer here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/19220/2212) makes a reference to "Yahshua Ha-Maschiach", whom we have to infer is Jesus.

Q: What are the intended purposes by those who would use "unusual" names for God or Jesus?

My speculative answer is that such persons believe they are beholden to a specially refined orthodoxy-- *hey we all do to some extent*-- but believe they need to refer to a more special name in order to clue others that they have many false ideas about the "god" they worship.

If this answer is wrong, I beg forgiveness and correction.

Comment: They're descriptive of who God is. Jehovah Jireh is "The Lord will provide." Yahshua Ha Mashiach is "Jesus the Messiah." Some people use these names to help them remember what He can do - when sick Jehovah Rapha (The Lord who heals) reminds them He is greater, etc.

Comment: The use of (approximate) transliterations of scriptural names/titles may be an indication of exclusiveness or a desire for authenticity (both "specially refined orthodoxy") but such might also be used to spur curiosity about such titles. For Jews, Hebrew-based titles would also be more appealing (affirming the OT and that the gospel is "first for the Jew")--perhaps not terribly dissimilar to using KJV for the familiarity/emotional impact.

Answer (score 4):

some of the Names come from the difference in Language throughout the Bible.
Greek, Jewish, etc

that paired with what God can do or will do or who He is, makes a compound name of description like

> Yahshua Ha Mashiach is "Jesus the Messiah."

or

> Jehovah Rapha (The Lord who heals)

they are all names for the same God, to better describe who He is and what He does.

there are many compound names for Him throughout the Bible.

1. Elohim or El "Strong One"
2. Yahweh (YHWH) "to exist, be" {see Link below}
3. Adonai "Master, Owner"
4. Theos Greek Translated "God"
5. Kurios Greek Translated "Lord"
6. Despotes Greek Translated "Master"
7. Father

of which many Compound names are given

1. El Shaddai "God Almighty"
2. El Elyon "The Most High God"
3. El Olam "The Everlasting God"

And

1. Yahweh Jireh (Yireh) “The Lord will provide.”
2. Yahweh Nissi “The Lord is my Banner.”
3. Yahweh Shalom “The Lord is Peace.”
4. Yahweh Sabbaoth “The Lord of Hosts.”
5. Yahweh Maccaddeshcem “The Lord your Sanctifier.”
6. Yahweh Ro’i  “The Lord my Shepherd.”
7. Yahweh Tsidkenu “The Lord our Righteousness.”
8. Yahweh Shammah “The Lord is there.”
9. Yahweh Elohim Israel “The Lord, the God of Israel.”

there are many more than just these, but the resource that I used is a Website

[The Names of God](https://bible.org/article/names-god)

it explains slightly better than I have and gives more insight into some of these names.

Really these Names are just descriptors of God

Answer (score 1):

God refers to himself as **I am that I am**, more accurately in Hebrew **I Will Be What I Will Be**

> Exo 3:14  And God said unto Moses, **I AM THAT I AM**: and he said, Thus
>   shalt thou say unto the children of Israel, I AM hath sent me unto
>   you.

He is infinite we are not. So as we discover more about him it is only natural that we need multiple ways of describing him as we grown in knowledge of him and his attributes. He is complete but to us sometimes he appears bigger as we draw closer and spend more time with him (as Lucy once said to Aslan in one of CS Lewis stories [prince Caspian](http://www.goodreads.com/work/quotes/3348636-prince-caspian-the-return-to-narnia)).

> “Aslan" said Lucy "you're bigger". "That is because you are older,
>   little one" answered he. "Not because you are?" "I am not. But every
>   year you grow, you will find me bigger".”  ― C.S. Lewis, Prince
>   Caspian: The Return to Narnia

Comment: I like the answer, but I am not sure that quoting from CS Lewis is considered On-Topic here.  I completely agree, just not sure it fits with the layout of this site.